# Is it possible to remove startup.cs file to remain with Program.cs after upgrading to .net 6.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was upgrading my ASP.NET Core MVC web app to .NET 6 and the startup file has been retained.
I wanted to create a WebApplication object as in :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

Then an error came so I solved it by adding a using directive to the Program.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
```

I am asking if it is possible to not have to add these multiple directives, because in .NET 6 you do not need to add the above directive to create a WebApplication object. How can I eliminate startup.cs and remain only with Program.cs in my project?

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET 6, the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK has a number of *[implicit using directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier)* that are defined, including for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder`. However, those require the `ImplicitUsings` property to be enabled for your project, otherwise they'll simply be ignored. The default new project template for .NET 6 has that in it, hence why it "works" with a new project.

To enable that with an existing project created before .NET 6, simply stick that in a property group in your `.csproj`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings> <!-- this -->
</PropertyGroup>
```